# Get Value of string array since string

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a string array which contains elements. These elements consist of a word and a color:

```
Array [0]: word = "Word1", Color = "Green"
Array [1]: word = "Word2", Color = "Blue"
Array [2]: word = "Word3", Color = "Yellow"
```

Is it possible to recover (in one line) the color since the word? 
Without loop in the array ?

regards,

Comment: Yes, with linq. Do u know it?

Comment: or use `Dictionary` instead...

Comment: With the where clause ? how to do ? thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit?  Do you mean to ask: "Is it possible to, given a word, find the color, in one line?"  Is that your question?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the LINQ `First()` method:

```
Color word2color = elementArray.First(e => e.word == "Word2").Color
```

Answer (score 2):

But, based on your comments:

```
// Assuming your object looks like this from your question
class MyObject {
        public string Word { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

You could do something like this:

```
MyObject[] data = ... ;
var fromWord1 = data.First(x => x.Word == "Word1").Color;
Console.WriteLine(fromWord1);
```

But, it's probably better to use a dictionary and grab them as you need.

```
MyObject[] data = ... ;
var dict = data.ToDictionary(x => x.Word, x => x.Color);
Console.WriteLine(dict["Word1"]);
```

Comment: Either post answer (your post looks like one) or wait till you can comment. Please avoid all sorts of "thank you", "new here", "can't comment" content in posts as they rarely related to problem/solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
Var myword = "someword";

Var ele = elementArray.FirstOrDefault(e => e.word.ToUpper() == myword.ToUpper());

If(ele != null) 
 // do something with ele.Color
```

Answer (score 0):

This code shows how to store the color in an array.

code :

```
 class Word {
            public string Word { get; set; }
            public string Color { get; set; }
    }

    class array
    {
        public Word[] array1 { get; set; }
        public Word[] array2 { get; set; }
    }

    array[] array = new array[1];
    array[0] = new array()
    {
        array1 = new Word[]
        {
            new Word()
            {
                Word = "Word1",
                Color = "Blue"
            },
            new Word()
            {
                Word = "Word2",
                Color = "Green"
            },
            new Word()
            {
                Word = "Word3",
                Color = "Yellow"
            }
        },
        array2 = new Word[]
        {
            new Word()
            {
                Word = "Word4",
                Color = "Black"
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: delete it, since its not an answer